# Empty result at fetch request with ssr rendring

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm need you suggestion how implement load a items by API and  server side rendering . My ssr is work with help express and babel. I have this component:

```
class MyApp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {result: []}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //request to api and set result in state
    }
    render() {
        return (<div>{this.state.result}</div>)
    }
}
```

I always get an empty component when rendering. How to make it rendered only after get the data from Api. My render is work by example: https://medium.com/styled-components/the-simple-guide-to-server-side-rendering-react-with-styled-components-d31c6b2b8fbf Thanks

Comment: Your state have a syntax error change it to `this.state  = {result: []}`

Comment: No, it my mistake at write this post. Thanks

Comment: Read section in react docs regarding "conditional rendering"

Comment: @SergBombermen you've asked many questions without accepting answers - have those answers not been correct?

Answer (score 0):

None of the react component lifecycle hooks will block rendering, which you need to ensure data fetching finishes before rendering, to get SSR. There are libraries that can help with this depending on your data management.

[redux-connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-connect) is one, which lets you define blocking promises in a `asyncConnect` decorator.

[react-data-fetching-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-fetching-components) is not redux specific and lets you define blocking promises in `withInitialData`

[react-ssr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ssr) is similar, with a `fetchData` static method.

[Next.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js) is also a popular framework that does SSR out of the box with minimal configuration.

There might be a way to do this with React's built in APIs now, but I'm not sure. In general you need to add your own blocking data fetching abstraction on the server.